# Translating jQuery to Watir

Tags: ruby, watir

It's entirely possible that I'm missing something fundamental, but this is a new realm for me and I could use some pointers. I'm getting started using Ruby and Watir to drive/test a web application that's all AJAX-built. Many of the items don't have explicit classes/ids, and the dev team of course uses jQuery to get to them. I'm looking for a way to translate their jQuery into Watir to use/modify/check values of the same objects.

For example, they use this to see if there are values in a data grid's fifth column:

```
$("div.dataTable table tbody tr").has("td:eq(4):not(:empty)").length > 0
```

How would I go about doing something similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make the same check in Watir using:

```
#Get the rows of the table (assuming there is just one dataTable)
table_trs = browser.div(:class, 'dataTable').table.tbody.trs

#Find how many rows have data in the 5th cell
#  Note that both jQuery and Watir are 0-based index (ie 4 means 5th cell)
rows_with_data = table_trs.count{ |tr| tr.td(:index, 4).text != '' }

#Do your comparison
rows_with_data > 0
```

You can write it all as one line, but I broke it up here for readability.

Comment: thanks, I think that's exactly what I was looking to do; I'll give it a go.
I've been looking through https://github.com/watir/watirspec to try to find all the objects, but missed trs. Is there a better (for browsing/searching) resource?

Comment: Due to the dynamic way the classes are generated, there is no good documentation of all the possible objects. But Watir supports all standard elements, which can be accessed as a single element (ex "tr") or collection ("trs"). If you use the same format (ie the tag name pluralized or not) for any tag type, it should work. The rdocs are useful once you get used to them - [watir-classic](http://rdoc.info/gems/watir-classic/frames) or [watir-webdriver](http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/frames).

Comment: gotcha.  It looks like this
table_trs.count{ |tr| tr.td(:index, 4).text != '' }

Comment: argh. I got interrupted.  anyway...   It looks like 
table_trs.count{ |tr| tr.td(:index, 4).text != '' }  gets translated into using {:index=>4, :tag_name=>"td"} which throws  Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException.

Comment: Can you share the html of the page so I can reproduce the problem?

Comment: it's from an internal app, but I've pulled the div and table out and put a sample at http://steven.vorefamily.net/test-grid/ and verified that my script is getting the same error there.

Comment: Ah. Sorry, I did not realize that the `tbody` part was important (usually its not). Your table has a `thead` section with one of the rows having fewer td/th elements, which is what confused the script. Adding the reference to the `tbody` in the first line fixes the problem.

Comment: @JustinKo: actually, there is a table of all elements that Watir supports: http://watir.github.com/watirbook/reference/elements.htm but it is a year old. Update coming soon.

Comment: @JustinKo most excellent, that works great- thank you very much. Željko Filipin thanks for passing along the info.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [Pincers](http://github.com/platanus/pincers). It's a small ruby gem, like Watir, but offers an API similar to jQuery on top of Webdriver.

Example:

```
require('selenium-webdriver')
require('pincers')
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
pincers = Pincers.for_webdriver driver
pincers.goto 'www.somesite.com'
pincers.css('a#link-id').click
```

(Disclosure: I work at Platanus.)